# Sound Script Play on/off

Tags: javascript

We are working on a project that has a page that we are comparing 4 different sounds.  The script we are using plays each sound fine however you can press each link and all 4 can play at the same time.  We are trying to figure out how to make it so that only one sound will play at one time.  If you press sound "A" then press sound "B", sound "A" should turn off and "B" will play.

```
var html5_audiotypes={ 
"mp3": "audio/mpeg",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
}
function createsoundbite(sound){
var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
if (html5audio.canPlayType){ 
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
        sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
        if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
            sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
        html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
    }
    html5audio.load()
    html5audio.playclip=function(){
        html5audio.pause()
        html5audio.currentTime=0
        html5audio.play()
    }
    return html5audio
}
```